# Magento2.3.2: decrease stock quantity on invoice generate

Tags: magento2, invoice, inventory, place-order

I created the module for.

`1. Decrease Stock quantity  when  invoice  generate and`
`2. decrease of salable quantity and actual stock" after creating the ship.`

But the module is not working properly actually salable quantity decrease twice after invoice generate and stock quantity also decrease twice after ship generate. Now to proper decrement of stock and salable I added code $qty=0; in line number 89 in file`/vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api/Model/SourceDeductionService.php.` 
How can I override it in my below module `obsever.php`
any minor help will be appreciated
here my module.
**Meetanshi/Extension/registration.php**

```
<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Meetanshi_Extension',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Meetanshi/Extension/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Meetanshi_Extension" setup_version="2.0.0">
     </module>
</config>
```

**Meetanshi/Extension/UpdateInventory.php**

```
<?php
        namespace Meetanshi\Extension\Observer;
        use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
        use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
        use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
        class UpdateInventory implements ObserverInterface
        {
            protected $productRepository;
            protected $stockRegistry;
            public function __construct(
                ProductRepository $productRepository,
                StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
            )
            {
                $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
                $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
            }
            public function execute(Observer $observer)
            {
                try {
                    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
                    $invoiceItems = $invoice->getAllItems();
                    foreach ($invoiceItems as $item) {
                        $productId = $item->getProductId();
                        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
                        $sku = $product->getSku();
                        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
                        $qty = $stockItem->getQty() - $item->getQty();
                        $stockItem->setQty($qty);
                        $stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty);
                        $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Meetanshi/Extension/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="sales_order_invoice_save_after">
            <observer name="Meetanshi_sales_order_invoice_save_after" instance="Meetanshi\Extension\Observer\UpdateInventory"/>
        </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Do you want to override `SourceDeductionService` file right?

Comment: yes ....  need to put $qty=0 (this is for decrease stock qty 1)   on line  88.

Comment: But you didn't accept any answers even it is correct...To increase your reputation and for the one who is answering reputation and for others reference you must accept correct answers...

Comment: You can accept the `tick` mark near the answer...(Left side under the votes)

Comment: Thank you....Coming back to the question...declaring $qty=0 in line number 88 is correct?

Comment: You can override using class preference - https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/

Comment: I tried but getting this error.   please follow link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292131/magento2-3-2-override-vendor-magento-module-inventory-source-deduction-api-mode

Comment: Can you pls help me here? How to do that in M1 ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/296621/68281