# Magento 2: how can Override vendor\magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View.php to remove/disable "Ship" button

Tags: magento2, blocks, adminhtml, sales, remove

To  Disable/Remove “ship” Button from `sales->order->view (click) -> Ship`
I commented   in core file  `vendor\magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View.php`   below code .

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction(
       'Magento_Sales::ship'
) && $order->canShip() && !$order->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice()
) {
       $this->addButton(
            'order_ship',
            [
                 'label' => __('Ship'),
                 'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getShipUrl() . '\')',
                 'class' => 'ship'
            ]
       );
 }.
```

now how  can i  ovveride block to  remove this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to create your custom module to override sales block.
also, please check with below url which is very helpful to you how to override

https://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/

and add block with extends

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Order;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class View extends Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View {

public function functionname()  // which have default in Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View
{ 
return "Override Text"; 
}
}
```

Comment: please vote my question or answer .. I have less reputation score to ask important and complicated question.

Comment: thanks to you support ...  please have a look  this link  if you submit your effort https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291115/magento2-3-2-decrease-stock-quantity-on-invoice-generate

Answer (score 0):

To remove `ship` button in admin order view page

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="remove_ship_button" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\RemoveButton" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/RemoveButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class RemoveButton
{
    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {

        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
            $buttonList->remove('order_ship');//Button id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: di.xml will  be   in   app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml...?

Comment: Yes.....It either be in any one folder...

Comment: it is area specific, you wanted to hide button in admin panel so I added di.xml in adminhtml area....If you add di.xml in etc folder it will take this as global area. So it will work both frontend and adminhtml.

Comment: thanks its work nicely

Comment: please  have a look  below link ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291115/magento2-3-2-decrease-stock-quantity-on-invoice-generate

Comment: Ok If it is correct solution then accept the answer.